# New to DialogFlow, proper values won't appear when referencing them

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm working my way through the tutorial and I am pretty sure I'm following it closely but it doesn't seem to be working.

[image]

I think I've successfully connected the value with the entity, then referenced said value in the response. But it seems like the entity is not responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the text response, but it seems unlikely this will do what you think it does.

As you've written it, the Intent will match if a user says something like "What is the February 10th"? Which doesn't make much sense.

Specifying a parameter against the sample phrase means that you expect the user to say something that matches that parameter in that place. In this case, you're saying the parameter is of type `@sys.date`, so you're expecting them to say a date of some sort (there are a variety of possible things that will match).

If you want the user to say "What is the date?" as a phrase, then the "date" part shouldn't be associated with a parameter. You'll then need to fill in some value for the reply - likely through a webhook.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I guess I'm still confused. I'm in the tutorial and it seems like I'm following it correctly. In the text response I put "The date is $date" which should reference the @sys.date entity shouldnt it?

Comment: Yes, but what are you saying that you think will invoke this intent? And what is it replying?

Comment: I thought that $date would invoke the system entity. So when the user mentioned "date" the response would appear. I guess I got that wrong. I just learned I would need to use a word like "tomorrow" for example

Comment: I guess what I was thinking was that $date associated the string "date" in the users question. Which is wrong